# Парсинг страницы с прогрузкой скриптов, phantomjs

Tags: парсер, curl, simple-html-dom, phantomjs

Нужно спарсить страницу https://dashboard.kitopiconnect.com/login. Обычные методы типа curl, simplehtmldom не помогают. Перешел к phantomjs. На просторах интернета нашел и доработал следующий код:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'https://dashboard.kitopiconnect.com/login';
page.settings.loadImages = true;
page.settings.resourceTimeout = 100000;
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;
page.settings.onLoadFinished = true;
page.open(url, function (status) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // код, который должен выполнятся после полной загрузки страницы

    page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js', function () {

        console.log('\n Evaluate Page \n');
        // Sandboxed
        var images = page.evaluate(function () {
            var images = [];
            function getImgDimensions($i) {
                return {
                    top: $i.offset().top,
                    left: $i.offset().left,
                    width: $i.width(),
                    height: $i.height(),
                }
            }
            $('img').each(function () {
                var img = getImgDimensions($(this));
                images.push(img);
            });

            return images;
        });
        console.log(images.length);


        images.forEach(function (imageObj, index, array) {
            page.clipRect = imageObj;
            page.render('images/' + index + '.png');
        });

        // Exit the session
        phantom.exit();
    });

    console.log("Status: " + status);
            if (status === "success") {
        page.render('example.png');
        phantom.exit();
    }
  }, 10000); // задержка
});
```

НО,к сожалению, выводит скриншот пустой страницы, а точнее вообще ничего. Такое ощущение, что js скрипты не подгружаются. Кто-нибудь знает, в каком направлении лучше двигаться или что можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

у phantomjs довольно старый движок, он не поддерживает некоторые важные функции, например:

```
function.prototype.bind
```

как это обойти можете почитать здесь:
[один из вариантов решения проблемы](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521)

так же можете попробовать использовать форк [Casper.js](https://www.casperjs.org/)

думаю это решит вашу проблему.

Comment: Благодарю за наводку, попробую)